# Swift Query Request crashing when value is null

Tags: ios, swift

Query results retrieved

```
 "Adjusted_Lease_Value__c" = "0.0";
    "Amount_Financed__c" = "23520.64";
    "Assignment_Amount__c" = "19220.21";
    "Category__c" = 4;
    "Charge_Off_Amount__c" = "0.0";
    "Committed_Funds__c" = "19220.21";
    "Date_Assigned_Back_to_ACG__c" = "<null>"
```

How I'm retrieving them:

```
// Initial Access to Salesforce in order to query data
client.performLogin(accessUsername, password: accessPassword, fail:{ (fail) in

}) { (success) in

self.queryResult = self.client.query(getCasesSQL2)

for o: Any in self.queryResult.records() {

// This line fails
let test = (o as AnyObject).fieldValue("Date_Assigned_Back_to_ACG__c") as! String

// This works no problem
let AmountFinanced = ((o as AnyObject).fieldValue("Amount_Financed__c") as! String

}
```

When the query result is **"null"** it crashes the app. What should I do?

Comment: What type is `self`? What type is `self.queryResult.records()`? You are casting to `Any` and then to `String` without doing any type-checking or safe unwrapping of `Optional` so if the cast fails of course you'll crash. You'll need to post more code in order for us to figure out what's really going on.

Comment: its an Assync Call. Can you show me the proper way to do this if im doing it incorrectly?

Comment: That doesn't shed much light on the problem.

Comment: how does it not? QueryResults are whats printed above its retriving the results. It crashes when its null and i dont know if im unwrapping things correctly

Comment: Casting an object into `Any` ignores all type information which goes against type safety, an important principle in Swift. If you do need to cast then use `as?` instead of `as!` so that you can get an `Optional` and properly test the cast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it may nil then do not use forced conversion.

```
self.queryResult = self.client.query(getCasesSQL2)

for o: Any in self.queryResult.records() {

   let test = (o as AnyObject).fieldValue("Date_Assigned_Back_to_ACG__c") as? String

   let amountFinanced = ((o as AnyObject).fieldValue("Amount_Financed__c") as? String

}
```

Comment: you are great :)

Comment: Why do I get the feeling that the OP blindly put your changes into their code and it stopped crashing, so they think "ok, all good!" without understanding what's going on at all?

Comment: If you use force unwrapping and value is nil then it will be crashed so I have used optional.

Comment: @DuncanC getting a second eye is never harmfull. Sorry your having a bad day.

Comment: spread your knowledge not your pointless opinion. Your the OP.